# Soma de data com condição?

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma base com as 3 colunas e uma que criei.

```
╔═══════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║             DATA          ║       LATITU        ║         LONGIT         ║  ROW      ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬═════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║    2021-02-10 10:32:00    ║  -27,0960066666667  ║     -52,6380843333333  ║    1      ║
║    2021-02-10 09:28:00    ║  -27,0960966666667  ║     -52,6380933333333  ║    2      ║
║    2021-02-10 08:27:00    ║  -27,0960966666667  ║     -52,6380933333333  ║    1      ║
║    2021-02-10 07:26:00    ║  -27,0961566666667  ║     -52,6380950000000  ║    1      ║
║    2021-02-10 06:24:00    ║  -27,0961466666667  ║     -52,6381016666667  ║    2      ║
║    2021-02-10 05:24:00    ║  -27,0961466666667  ║     -52,6381016666667  ║    1      ║
║    2021-02-10 03:23:00    ║  -27,0963583333333  ║     -52,6381350000000  ║    1      ║
╚═══════════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Meu objetivo é criar uma coluna que soma a coluna DATA no formato (`hh:mm`) enquanto esta em movimento (as colunas `LATITU` e `LONGIT` são valores diferente), zerar quando parar e reiniciar a soma ao se movimentar novamente. (*Lembrando que resumi os dados aqui, pois na base real a data vem a cada 5 minutos e a coluna ROW as vezes chega até em uma sequencia que 100*).

***Exemplo:***

---

`TIME`:

```
01:04

00:00

02:03

01:02

00:00

02:01

00:00 - INICIO
```

Para auxiliar criei essa coluna chamada "ROW", nela sempre que a Latitude e Longitude é diferente (esta em movimento) ela resulta em "1" e quando a LAT/LONG for igual (estiver parado) inicia uma sequencia (1,2,3,4) até mudar a lat/long (retornar ao movimento) onde ela resulta novamente em 1.

`SQL`:

```
SELECT DATA, LATITU, LONGIT, ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY LATITU,LONGIT ORDER BY DATA ASC) as ROW  
FROM TABELA_LATLONG
ORDER BY 
DATA DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando uma CTE recursiva:

```
WITH
  CTE_RN AS
  (
    SELECT
      DATA,
      LATITU,
      LONGIT,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA) AS RN
    FROM TABELA_LATLONG
  ),
  
  CTE_REC AS
  (
    SELECT
      DATA,
      LATITU,
      LONGIT,
      RN,
      DATA AS DATA_INI,
      CAST('00:00' AS DATETIME) AS TEMPO
    FROM CTE_RN
    WHERE
      RN = 1
      
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      N.DATA,
      N.LATITU,
      N.LONGIT,
      N.RN,
      CASE WHEN C.LATITU = N.LATITU AND C.LONGIT = N.LONGIT
        THEN N.DATA
        ELSE C.DATA_INI
      END,
      CASE WHEN C.LATITU = N.LATITU AND C.LONGIT = N.LONGIT
        THEN CAST('00:00' AS DATETIME)
        ELSE 
          DATEADD
            (MINUTE,
             DATEDIFF
               (MINUTE,
                C.DATA_INI,
                N.DATA),
             0)
      END     
    FROM CTE_REC AS C
    INNER JOIN CTE_RN AS N
      ON N.RN = C.RN + 1
  )

SELECT
  DATA,
  LATITU,
  LONGIT,
  TEMPO
FROM CTE_REC
ORDER BY 
  DATA DESC
```

E uma outra sugestão utilizando uma subquery:

```
WITH CTE_RN AS
(
  SELECT 
    DATA, 
    LATITU, 
    LONGIT, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LATITU,LONGIT ORDER BY DATA ASC) as ROW_PART,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA ASC) as ROW_GERAL
  FROM TABELA_LATLONG
)

SELECT
  T.DATA,
  T.LATITU,
  T.LONGIT,
  CASE WHEN ROW_GERAL = 1 OR ROW_PART > 1 
    THEN CAST('00:00' AS DATETIME)
    ELSE
      DATEADD
        (MINUTE,
         DATEDIFF
           (MINUTE, 
            (SELECT TOP(1) I.DATA FROM CTE_RN AS I
             WHERE
               I.DATA < T.DATA AND
               (I.ROW_GERAL = 1 OR I.ROW_PART > 1)
             ORDER BY
               I.DATA DESC),
            T.DATA),
         0)
  END AS TEMPO
FROM CTE_RN AS T
ORDER BY 
  T.DATA DESC
```

**Edit**: Segue abaixo a versão com subquery modificada para formatar a coluna Tempo no formato hh:mm

```
WITH CTE_RN AS
(
  SELECT 
    DATA, 
    LATITU, 
    LONGIT, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LATITU,LONGIT ORDER BY DATA ASC) as ROW_PART,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATA ASC) as ROW_GERAL
  FROM TABELA_LATLONG
)

SELECT
  T.DATA,
  T.LATITU,
  T.LONGIT,
  CASE WHEN ROW_GERAL = 1 OR ROW_PART > 1 
    THEN '00:00'
    ELSE
      LEFT
        (CONVERT
           (VARCHAR(10),
            DATEADD
              (MINUTE,
               DATEDIFF
                 (MINUTE, 
                  (SELECT TOP(1) I.DATA FROM CTE_RN AS I
                   WHERE
                     I.DATA < T.DATA AND
                     (I.ROW_GERAL = 1 OR I.ROW_PART > 1)
                   ORDER BY
                     I.DATA DESC),
                  T.DATA),
               0),
            108),
         5)   
  END AS TEMPO
FROM CTE_RN AS T
ORDER BY 
  T.DATA DESC
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Deu certo com a SUBQUERY, porém a coluna TEMPO trouxe numa formatação não muito amigável, trouxe como "aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:nnn". Como posso alterar para trazer somente em hh:mm?

Comment: A quantidade vai ser sempre inferior a 24 horas? Acho que a preferência seria fazer a formatação na camada de apresentação, mas se for sempre inferior a 24 horas você pode alterar DateTime para Time no Cast e o parâmetro 0 do DateAdd para Cast('00:00' as Time)

Comment: Sim no meu caso não passa de 24hrs, com o cast como voce falou trouxe o resultado com o formato "hh:mm:ss:nnnn", mas no meu caso preciso apenas do "hh:mm". Como posso alterar para ele? tentei também utilizar um convert no lugar do cast "CONVERT (varchar,'00:00',108)", mas também sem sucesso

Comment: Editei a resposta para acrescentar outra sugestão com a formatação na versão com a subquery

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado.